# windows findstr and unc paths

Tags: windows, cmd, findstr

I have a list of unc paths:

```
\\server1\share1
\\server1\share1\subfolder1
\\server1\share2\subfolder1
\\server2\share1
```

I want only to find:

```
\\server1\share1\subfolder1
\\server1\share2\subfolder1
```

I tried:

```
findstr /r /i "\\\\*.*\\*.*\\*.*"
```

but it gives me the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FINDSTR /r /i "\\\\.*\\.*\\.*"
```

`\` escapes `\`...

Answer (score 0):

findstr /s /p "theword" "\machinename\sharename*"
/s is recursive /p is skip binary